# Why is my denoised image gets blurred after using non local means algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, blur, noise, noise-reduction

I've implemented non-local means algorithm and after trying and reading everything I still can't find the answer, why it gets so blurred instead of removing the noise.

I set search window to 21, neighborhood window to 3 and h=4, as it was recommended by many sites if the standard deviation of the noise was below 15. Has anyone had this kind of problem?

Comment: Not many people will know about non-local means, so you should include [a link to the paper](http://bengal.missouri.edu/~kes25c/nl2.pdf). You should also include your code...

Comment: Also, relevant images that show your noisy images as well as the filtered results would be nice too.  You don't have enough reputation to attach images, so if you can place external links to them on public sharing websites, we will embed them into your post.  It **also** depends on what **kind of noise** you are trying to remove.  NLM denoising is only tailored for specific kinds of noise. You should probably add in what **kind of noise** you are trying to remove **and the weighting function you're using**. What you have described isn't enough to diagnose what's wrong with your implementation.

Comment: Also, this link with the paper and source code to NLM denoising may help: http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2011/bcm_nlm/

Comment: Could you show what you did and we'll be able to assist you?